# How do I properly create custom text codecs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm digging through some old binaries that contain (among other things) text. Their text frequently uses custom character encodings for Reasons, and I want to be able to read and rewrite them.

It seems to me that the appropriate way to do this is to create a custom codec using the [standard codecs library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html). Unfortunately its documentation is both colossal and entirely bereft of examples. Google turns up a few, but only for python2, and I'm using 3.

I'm looking for a minimal example of how to use the codecs library to implement a custom character encoding.

Comment: Not minimal, but this might be a good place to start: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/tools/hexlify_codec.py

Comment: I'm interested in this one also:  https://github.com/asottile/future-fstrings

Comment: @JamesLim: Accepted. I wasn't really expecting an answer after so long.

Comment: This [section in PyMOTW](https://pymotw.com/3/codecs/index.html#defining-a-custom-encoding) on defining a custom encoding is worth reading.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You asked for minimal!

- Write a encode function and a decode function.
- Write a "search function" that returns a `CodecInfo` object constructed from the above encoder and decoder.
- Use [codec.register](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.register) to register a function that returns the above `CodecInfo` object.

Here is an example that converts the lowercase letters a-z to 0-25 in order.

```
import codecs
import string

from typing import Tuple

# prepare map from numbers to letters
_encode_table = {str(number): bytes(letter, 'ascii') for number, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}

# prepare inverse map
_decode_table = {ord(v): k for k, v in _encode_table.items()}


def custom_encode(text: str) -> Tuple[bytes, int]:
    # example encoder that converts ints to letters
    # see https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.Codec.encode
    return b''.join(_encode_table[x] for x in text), len(text)


def custom_decode(binary: bytes) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    # example decoder that converts letters to ints
    # see https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.Codec.decode
    return ''.join(_decode_table[x] for x in binary), len(binary)


def custom_search_function(encoding_name):
    return codecs.CodecInfo(custom_encode, custom_decode, name='Reasons')


def main():

    # register your custom codec
    # note that CodecInfo.name is used later
    codecs.register(custom_search_function)

    binary = b'abcdefg'
    # decode letters to numbers
    text = codecs.decode(binary, encoding='Reasons')
    print(text)
    # encode numbers to letters
    binary2 = codecs.encode(text, encoding='Reasons')
    print(binary2)
    # encode(decode(...)) should be an identity function
    assert binary == binary2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running this prints

```
$ python codec_example.py
0123456
b'abcdefg'
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codec-objects for details on the `Codec` interface. In particular, the decode function

> ... decodes the object *input* and returns a tuple (output object, length
>   consumed).

whereas the encode function

> ... encodes the object *input* and returns a tuple (output object, length consumed).

Note that you should also worry about handling streams, incremental encoding/decoding, as well as error handling. For a more complete example, refer to the [hexlify codec](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/tools/hexlify_codec.py) that @krs013 mentioned.

---

P.S. instead of of `codec.decode`, you can also use `codec.open(..., encoding='Reasons')`.

Comment: Nice work, believe I could follow this. :)  You might want to modify your links from '*/3.5/*' to '3' so they follow newer versions.

Comment: Hrm, wait a sec. This gets the point across, but I don't think those def lines are valid python...? Unless there's a different function def syntax that I've somehow managed to never see. [edit: never mind, it's type hinting. I learned something today.]

Answer (score 2):

While the online documentation is certainly sparse, you can get a lot more information by looking at [the source code](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.5.2/file/tip/Lib/codecs.py). The docstrings and comments are quite clear, and the definitions for the parent classes (Codec, IncrementalEncoder, etc.) are ready to be copy/pasted for a start to your codec (be sure to replace the `object` in each class definition with the name of the class you're inheriting from). It's also worth looking at the [example](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/tools/hexlify_codec.py) I linked to in the comments for how to assemble/register it.

I've been stuck at the same point as you for a while looking through this, so good luck! If I have time in a few days, I'll see about actually making that implementation and pasting/linking to it here.