# How can I handle custom unicode in python

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I have exported some excel files from oracle pl database and now when I open it with excel or from python pandas I see string in this form: ÎÀÎÓÀØÅÈÊÈ and it should be like: პაპუაშვილი.

I have tried all the string.encode(encoding).decode(decoding) pairs from encodings.aliases, and can not get the desired result.

What I figured out so far is that

```py
''.join(list(map(lambda x: chr(ord(x) + 4112), "ÎÀÎÓÀØÅÈÊÈ")))
```

gives me this string
Can I have some custom encoding or is there any way so I do not have to call this method every time?

Comment: you'll need to find out the encoding used... or detect it somehow

Comment: I loop over all encodings and there was not such one

Comment: somewhere between oracle and excel the data was incorrectly encoded/decoded/encoded/decoded

Comment: In excel I can choose a font and declare it correctly. I have a .ttf file can you tell me how can I use it?

Comment: nothing to do with the font. All to do with the encoding of the raw data.

Comment: desired_word = ''.join(list(map(lambda x: chr(ord(x) + 4112), unknown_word)))

for encoding, _ in aliases.items():
    for decoding, _ in aliases.items():
        if encoding == decoding:
            continue
        try:
            converted_word = unknown_word.encode(encoding).decode(decoding)
            if converted_word == desired_word:

                print(converted_word, encoding, decoding)
        except Exception:
            continue

Comment: Here it is there is not desired encoding decoding. Is there any way?

Comment: custom codec? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777818/how-do-i-properly-create-custom-text-codecs