# python3 custom encoding mik-bulgarian

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am trying to decode with python 3.8 a file that is in MIK-BULGARIAN encoding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIK_(character_set). It is an encoding that is identical with ASCII but bytes 128-191 are cyrilic letters. The file has both latin and cyrilic letters.
My current solution works well but is rather slow with big files. Can you give me some suggestions how to speed things up (I know this is a lumberjack approach and I am open to suggestions).

```
def opener(filename):

    f = open(filename, "rb")
    filetext = f.read()
    cadText = translate(filetext)
    f.close()
    return cadText

mikdict = {
    128: "А",
    129: "Б",
    130: "В",
    131: "Г",
    132: "Д",
    ....
    188: "ь",
    189: "э",
    190: "ю",
    191: "я"
  }
def translate(textbytes):
    goodText = ""
    for txtbyte in textbytes:
        if (txtbyte >= 128) and (txtbyte <= 191):
            letter = str(mikdict.get(txtbyte))
        else:
            letter = chr(txtbyte)
        goodText = goodText + letter
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777818/how-do-i-properly-create-custom-text-codecs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [str.translate gives TypeError - Translate takes one argument (2 given), worked in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175809/str-translate-gives-typeerror-translate-takes-one-argument-2-given-worked-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[code]Apparantly the right answer was to use map() and lambda, as it seems to be much more efficient than the my initial snippet.

```
def translate(input):
    newChars = map(lambda x: bytes([x]) if (x < 128) else bytes(mik.mikdict.get(x), "utf-8") if (x <= 191) and (x >= 128) else b"", input)
    res = b''.join(newChars).decode("utf-8")
return res
```

Comment: This code is very useful, thanks. I just changed "mik.mikdict.get(x)" with "mikdict.get(x)". A side effect is that it adds an extra new line after each existing new line in my file. Do you now how this can be prevented?

Comment: update to previous comment : Sorry, I found that the extra new line had nothing to do with your code. The problem was in the way I opened a file to write the output. It should be like this: out=open('outputFileName.txt', 'w', newline=''). The newline parameter should be set explicitly to ''.